# Determine the basis of a composite field extension using the primitive element

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I have been confusing myself a lot with the following and I am sure I must be missing something obvious, so sorry for this probably stupid question.

Given $\alpha = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$  and $\beta = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$, we extend the rational numbers to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(\beta)$.
We determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ to be $x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$ and the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ to be $x^4-16x^2+4$.
Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 4$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$ and so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 16$.
We can now construct the following basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$:

$\mathcal{B} = \{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \beta, \alpha\beta, \alpha^2\beta, \alpha^3\beta, \beta^2, \alpha\beta^2, \alpha^2\beta^2, \alpha^3\beta^2, \beta^3, \alpha\beta^3, \alpha^2\beta^3, \alpha^3\beta^3\}$

(I hope this is correct so far.)

The roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ are

$\alpha = \alpha_1 = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$

$\alpha_2 = -\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$

$\alpha_3 = -\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$

$\alpha_4 = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$

The roots of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ are

$\beta = \beta_1 = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$

$\beta_2 = -\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$

$\beta_3 = -\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$

$\beta_4 = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$

Now we can choose some primitive element $\gamma = \alpha + c\beta$ , where $c \neq \frac{\alpha_i - \alpha_1}{\beta_j + \beta_1}$ ($i = 1, 2, 3, 4$ and $j = 1, 2, 3, 4$).
We choose $c = -1$ and get $\gamma = \sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$.

(Now my confusion comes in.)

We can now determine the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ to be $x^8 - 76x^6 + 1414x^4 - 6540x^2 + 225$.
This means that $[\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$. (Contradicting the previous result that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 16$.)

There must be something really obvious I am missing. Could anybody please point out my mistake?

Comment: 1) In both your minimal polynomials for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you mean $x^2$ instead of $x$. 2) You write (after correction): "We determine...the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ to be $x^4-16x^2+4$". How? Yes, $\beta$ is a root of this polynomial, but it turns out to be reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$: $x^4 - 16 x^2 + 4 = (x^2 + (-\alpha^3 + 11 \alpha) x - 2)(x^2 + (\alpha^3 - 11 \alpha) x - 2)$.

Comment: The computation of degree $16$ is not correct. Note that $a,b$ should be $\alpha,\beta$. In fact, the field extension is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$, which degree $8$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant $x^2$ in the two polynomials (will fix that). So my mistake was that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 2 \neq 4$. Thank you very much @ViktorVaughn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You write: "We determine...the minimal polynomial of $$ over $ℚ()$ to be $^4−16 ^2+4$". How? Yes, $$ is a root of this polynomial, but it turns out to be reducible over $ℚ()$:
> $$
> ^4 − 16 ^2 + 4 = (^2+(−^3+11)−2)(^2+(^3−11)−2)
> $$ – Viktor Vaughn

> The computation of degree 16 is not correct. In fact, the field extension is $ℚ(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$, which is degree $8$ over $ℚ$. – Dietrich Burde